# How do you construct an object without initializing it? (.net)

Tags: .net, serialization, initialization, object-construction

When you new an object in C# a few things must happen:

1. memory for the object is created, and whatever other book-keeping CLR whats to do
2. fields are initialized to default values
3. the constructor is invoked

Serialization frameworks seem to have some magical way to do 1 without doing 2 and 3. Or maybe it's not so magical after all. How would you do the same (skip 2 and 3) if you are writing your own deserialization code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Create object instance without invoking constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296584/c-create-object-instance-without-invoking-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary formatter uses methods of [FormatterServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.aspx), like [GetUninitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx).